# Add unique class to section (PHP)

Tags: php, css, content-management-system

My web design has set me up a CMS but I have some issues.

Currently, sections are all using the same css tag .SectionOuterAlt or .SectionOuter (if there's more than one it becomes 'Alt'. Same applies for .SectionInner.

I have searched for 'SectionOuter' and discovered this line of code. It looks to me like it adds the 'Alt' onto it.

Problem is that I need each section to be unique so I can add css. It would be great if I could keep 'SectionOuter' and perhaps 'SectionOuterAlt' but include a unique css class to each one so that I can make unique changes to each individual section.

```
<section class="SectionOuter<?php echo $alt; ?>">
<section class="SectionInner<?php echo $alt; ?>">
```

Could anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: Need to see all the code for a suggestion, there isn't much to go by here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the other answer won't work is because it is applying classes that might not be suitable, and potentially replacing other classes are are needed.

What you need to do is leave the existing classes untouched and add a *new* class that you can use for unique styling.

At the top of your page, you can add a global variable, e.g.

```
<?php $SectionCount = 0; ?>
```

Then where you want to add a unique class, you can do the following:

```
<section class="SectionOuter<?php echo $alt; ?> UniqueClass-<?php echo $SectionCount++; ?>" >
<section class="SectionInner<?php echo $alt; ?> UniqueClass-<?php echo $SectionCount++; ?>" >
```

This will automatically add a new, unique class to every section, called `UniqueClass-n` (where `n` is unique within the page) without affecting the existing functionality or styling. It is also not limited to just 2 numbers or sections per page.

**Making it global**

You could make this global in a number of ways, depending on how your pages are set up e.g.

1. Add a global variable into header code
2. Use a unique class on the page `body` to target each page (e.g. `.homepage .UniqueClass-1 {} .contactpage .UniqueClass-1 {}`  etc. )

However, without more information about how your current site is set up (the CMS, or what template files might exist to add the code into for example), we can't tell you exactly how you would achieve this.

**UPDATE:**

It's not really feasible to add a unique number to each section across all pages - it is possible but it would take as much (or more) effort than adding them manually (to make it persistent and consistent, it would have to be assigned to each section).

You could either:

1. use a combination of a unique class/id for the page body and the section class (as mentioned above) *or*
2. generate a new class for each section, based on some unique identifier of the page

In either case, you will need to use a unique identifier on each page. This will depend on how your pages are set up, but if you are using a CMS then each `<body>` element is likely to have a unique class added to it.

**1. combination of classes**

Your homepage could for example, have something like `<body class="homepage page-452">` and the About page might be: `<body class="page-about page-818">` etc.

In this case you can target the section on each specific page using a combination of these classes, e.g.

```
// target ONLY UniqueClass-1 on the page with the specified body class
.page-452 .UniqueClass-1 { /* CSS HERE FOR HOMEPAGE ONLY */ } 
.page-818 .UniqueClass-1 { /* CSS HERE FOR ABOUT PAGE ONLY */ }
```

Without knowing more about your CMS or the generated HTML, its difficult to give an exact answer, but this is how you can do it.

(I see in a comment you made since I started this answer that your CMS doesn't have a unique body class, so you eill need to use the next  option:)

**2. Generate a Unique Class**

Alternatively, to generate a unique class for each page, you could use the slug if your CMS generated one, or if the page title is always going to be unique, you could turn it into a string suitable for a classname by adding this to the top of the page where you declare $SectionCount, e.g.:

At the top of the page:

```
<?php 
$SectionCount = 0;
$pageClass = preg_replace( '/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]/', '', $pageTitle);
?>
```

Then you can create your unique class as follows:

```
<section class="SectionOuter<?php echo $alt; ?> ClassPrefix-<?php echo $pageClass."-".($SectionCount++); ?>" >
<section class="SectionInner<?php echo $alt; ?> ClassPrefix-<?php echo $pageClass."-".($SectionCount++); ?>" >
```

Now you can target each section of each page individually as follows:

```
.ClassPrefix-generated-page-class-1 { /* CSS HERE */ }
.ClassPrefix-generated-page-class-2 { /* CSS HERE */ }
/* etc */
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect. Now I just need to know how I can make each page generate a unique class so that I can do the css unique for each page and section. Thanks so much!

Comment: @LukeHall No problem! What CMS are you using? The more we know about the existing code, the better we can help :)

Comment: It is a custom CMS apparantly but the website looks like it is bootstrap. Sorry I can't be much of a help I'm not familar with a custom CMS before but it looks very simple to me. Just can't really describe it!

Comment: Not sure if this is any help, but the way they set up the meta tags was like this - 

if ($pageTitle) { 

So maybe we can add page title for each page as the custom css class? I have no idea - just might help :)

Comment: This is one of the pages also if that helps? As you can see it's in development so just playing about with this page. https://www.pearldroppools.co.uk/pool-servicing-and-cleaning

Comment: @LukeHall Take a look at the last section of my updated answer - I had already written the "combined classes" option when I saw your comment, so you will need to go with generating the class from the page title - note that this will only work when all the page titles are unique, but in a well made website they should be unique for SEO anyway :)

Comment: Thank you so much, it's perfect! You've saved me so much time - much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you wan unique values for each of the classes, then you can do something like this:

```
<?php

for ($k = 1; $k <= 2; $k++)
    echo '<section class="SectionOuter SectionOuterAlt SectionOuterAlt-' . $k . '">';

for ($k = 1; $k <= 2; $k++)
    echo '<section class="SectionInner SectionInnerAlt SectionInnerAlt-' . $k . '">';
```

The output would be something like this:

```
<section class="SectionOuter SectionOuterAlt SectionOuterAlt-1">
<section class="SectionOuter SectionOuterAlt SectionOuterAlt-2">
<section class="SectionInner SectionInnerAlt SectionInnerAlt-1">
<section class="SectionInner SectionInnerAlt SectionInnerAlt-2">
```

Comment: yup my bad sorry ._.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your reply! I had a strange issue where this occurs - https://ibb.co/P5gS2sp

It works though as it's making each section unique! However, it is using the same css class for each page. Is there a way that I can make it unique across all pages please, not just the one? 

Thank you!

Comment: This answer is going to break any existing functionality / styling that relies on the `SectionOuterAlt` and/or `SectionInner` and/or `SectionInnerAlt` classes and on the lack of the `SectionOuter` class.

Comment: Hmm the new updated code seems to break the website. The sections disappear.

Comment: May be the classes you wanted were not these?

Comment: Please see my comment above for why this answer is likely to cause problems - you can't just replace classes with different classes and expect it all to work!

Comment: I see the 'Alt' is added automatically I thought the CSS classes were handwritten by the developers

Comment: If we had it so that we keep the old css - but it adds a new unique class onto the end of it then that would be perfect. When I paste your current code it breaks the websites and the sections disappear. Your previous code worked great apart from 1. Piece of code appeared on the website and 2. It works for mulitple pages. Need it unique so that a section is unique across the entire site.

Comment: check the newly edited code now. Is that how you wanted the output?

Comment: @LukeHall Please see my answer that I added before this one was edited - as well as addressing the original problem, it also gives a more dynamic way to achieve this so that you can adapt to make it work globally. I wasn't going to add a separate answer because keidakida had been trying to help you, but as they ignored my comments that pointed out the changes they needed to make their answer work, I didn't have much of a choice :)